# Load into label a variable

Tags: php

I've read on this forum some stuff about this and this is my PHP code:

```
<?
$percorso = file("emma.txt");
while(list(,$value) = each($percorso)){
list($aboutme, $aboutme2) = split("[:]", $value);
#declaration trim()
$params["aboutme"] = trim($aboutme);
$params["aboutme2"] = trim($aboutme2);
#print results
//put aboutme in label
//put aboutme2 in label2
}
?>
```

Basically: I have a text file (`emma.txt`) that has some infos inside separated by a new line. Here you can see an eaxpmle:

data_1

data_2

data_3...

With that code I read the content of each single line and I'd like put the content into a label, but I don't know how to do it. This is the label: `<label name="lbl1">Nickname</label>`.

I was thinking to use the `$_GET[]` method, because I want set the labels' text with those text file lines. What can I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good ol'fashion PHP:

You would need to output the labels within the while loop like so:

```
<?
$percorso = file("emma.txt");
while(list(,$value) = each($percorso)){
list($aboutme, $aboutme2) = split("[:]", $value);
#declaration trim()
$params["aboutme"] = trim($aboutme);
$params["aboutme2"] = trim($aboutme2);
#print results
//put aboutme in label
//put aboutme2 in label2

// Method 1: Output each line via PHP echo:
echo "<label name='lbl1'>".$params['aboutme']."</label>";
// etc...

// Method 2: Output via break PHP for HTML:
?>

<label name='lbl2'><?php echo $params['aboutme2']; ?></label>
etc...

<?php
// If using Method 2, don't forget to resume PHP here!
}
?>
```

Comment: <form method="get" action="myloader.php"> <label name="lbl1"><?php echo $params["aboutme"]; ?></label> <label name="lbl2"><?php echo $params["aboutme2"]; ?></label> </form> <-- correct?

Comment: Yes assuming, a lot of things... let me know if you get errors

Comment: I have to put <?php // Resume PHP } ?> without any code inside?

Comment: Sorry if that added confusion, I updated the answer to clarify

Comment: Look: http://prntscr.com/1d8ioz . The background (it is an image) is the black table with z-index: -1 and the table has a lot of labels that contains the text (ns, 100, 600...). With that PHP script, I wanna read each single line of my text file and load it into a label on that table. I made what you said but I see a white page and the table + img disappears :(

Comment: I would need to see the entire code in that case, the code that renders your table etc.

Comment: Otherwise, jQuery would easily be able to populate labels, you can have you while loop populate the jQuery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XbjQe/ html and css, here you can see the PHP: http://pastebin.com/p4BD42Xv - I can't understand what is wrong